# Can anyone help me in exporting Sonarqube rules which are Inactive using Web API?

Tags: shell, command-line, sonarqube, sonarqube5.1, sonarqube-web

I'm currently using SonarQube v5.6 and I'm trying to export the list of the rules that are inactive. 
We can take "**BackUp**" of the rules that are active through the UI, but **I'm trying to do this using Web API supported by Sonarqube on command line**.

For Example: 
I'm trying to export the rules which are not active in sonarqube:
http://$sonarqubeServer/coding_rules#qprofile=$key|activation=false

Can anyone please help me how to go about this ?

Answer (score 1):

SonarQube Web API is pretty well documented (accessible from the footer of your server). [*api/rules*](https://sonarqube.com/web_api/api/rules) offers  *api/rules/search* which takes a bunch of parameters, including:

> - *activation* - Filter rules that are activated or deactivated on the selected Quality profile. Ignored if the parameter 'qprofile' is not
>     set.
> - *qprofile* - Key of Quality profile to filter on. Used only if the parameter 'activation' is set.

Bottom line, this request in the UI:
https://sonarqube.com/coding_rules#activation=false|qprofile=js-sonar-way-56838

Is equivalent to this Web API request:

```
https://sonarqube.com/api/rules/search?activation=no&qprofile=js-sonar-way-56838
```